# SQL: Extract 5 different Address into one list

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL coding and the office requested a printout of data to help them with printing mailing labels.

The database has up to 5 different address's for a student cnt1, cnt2, etc.  There is a flag for each cnt to determine if the cnt's should receive mail; cntx_recvmail=1

Each student can have up to 5 different address labels and it should be grouped by the student ID number.  Student 12345 if cnt1_flag=1, or cnt1_flag=2, etc. then
cnt1 name, street, city, state, zip
cnt2 name, street, city state, zip
ect. to cnt5

I need to pull out all cnt's who should receive mail in a list that includes the cnt's name, street, state, zip if cnt_recvmail=1. Any assistance would be appreciated.

This is an example of the code which works for cnt1:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name,
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_fname'),
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_lname'),
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_street'),
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_city'),
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_state'),
ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_zip')
FROM students s
WHERE s.enroll_status=0 
AND s.grade_level =9
AND ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt1_recvmail')=1;
```

The output should group by student ID #12345
cnt1name, cnt1street, cnt1state, cnt1zip
cnt2name, cnt2street, cnt2state, cnt2zip
ect to cnt5

Comment: Not an answer, but if you store "up to 5 addresses" in a row, your database layout should be improved. In Computer Science, there are only three numbers: 0, 1, and many. 5 is not one of them. ;)

Comment: And what exactly does `ps_customfields.getcf()` do?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: Oracle.  The system is PowerSchool for education and ps_customfields.getcf() is a custom field where the address is stored.

Comment: `getcf()` is **no** "a custom field" - it's a function that does something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a very simple answer. I should warn you, there are scenarios where this won't work, which is why people asked for more details in your question. For example, if your `ps_customfields.getcf()` **function** returns an error when it can't find any results.

It wasn't really clear from your question, but I think you want to show an address for a student (e.g. cnt4) only when the recvmail flag =1 (e.g. cnt4_recvmail=1). If this isn't what you want, please clarify and I'll update this answer.

EDIT: Oh! Well, if you want one address per row, that's actually a much simpler query. Try this out.

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name,
    cnt.x,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_fname') cnt_fname,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_lname') cnt_lname,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_street') cnt_street,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_city') cnt_city,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_state') cnt_state,
    ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_zip') cnt_zip
FROM students s
cross join (select level as x from dual connect by level <= 5) cnt
WHERE s.enroll_status=0 
AND s.grade_level =9
AND ps_customfields.getcf('students',id,'cnt' || cnt.x || '_recvmail')=1
order by 1
;
```

Also, it helps us a lot when you can make up an example - let's say one fake student name and 3 fake addresses, and then show us what that would look like in your results, like:

```
cnt1_recvmail=1, cnt2_recvmail=0, etc.

id   fn1 ln1   street1       city1      state1 zip1  fn2    ln2    street2  city2  state2 ... etc
S001 Bob Smith 1057 Main St. Washington DC     87234 (null) (null) (null)  (null) (null) ... etc
```

Comment: Kfinity,  Thank you.  I actually started with CASE then couldn't figure out how to get each address per line.The output should have one address per line for student#12345 and this could be up to cnt5.  The student may have 5 different address's with the recvmail=1 flag and each one requires a letter to go home to that address.  This could be Parent1, Parent2, CaseWork1, DCF1, Grandparent1 with each one living at a different mailing address.  The list is then use to print labels.

Comment: @ElizabethD, I edited the question to show one address per line. I think it's a much nicer query. Let me know how it works.

Comment: Yes, this works beautifully!  Thank you kfinity..Problem solved, World is saved.

Comment: Kfinity,  if I can bother you for one additional question.  The report needs to include grades 9 - 12.  When I change s.grade_level = 9, to >=9 no data returns.  I think this requires a loop by grade?